# I try to connect a test app to the reddit api. But error is occuring and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I get this error and I don't know why. Thanks in advance.
[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKBm1.png)

I think the error is occuring here in my reddit.service.ts folder

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RedditService{
    http: any;
    baseUrl: String;

    constructor(http:Http){
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/r';

    }

    getPosts(category, limit){
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/'+category+'/top.json?limit='+limit)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RedditService{
http: any;
baseUrl: String;

constructor(public http:Http){
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/r';
    this.getPosts();

}

getPosts(category, limit){
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/'+category+'/top.json?limit='+limit).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
 });
 }
}
```

Note : In the constructor method when you don't add the private or public keyword the service/Http variable is evaluated as a local variable, so it's destroyed at the end of the method call.

Comment: Hey @Priyank, I tried your code, but now its still not working:  public http is red underlined and this.getPosts as well.

Comment: @Caturix99 have you added import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; in your app.module.ts file and in import section?

Comment: yes I get a runtime error : undefined is Not an object.

Comment: And the two things I wrote above are still underlined